# Is there an API event for when person changes clock on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

I was wondering if there's some sort of system event that gets fired every time a user changes the time in Windows. I know there's a way to enable this in Windows' EventLog, but I was looking for a way to respond to this event programatically (like using the Windows API).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure from your question if you're working in managed or native code.  But if you're working in managed code you can use the TimeChanged event on the SystemEvents class.

[Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.TimeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx)

Comment: My apologies for not being completely clear. But yes, I will be running this on a managed environment so your answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

A [WM_TIMECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725498.aspx) message is sent whenever there is a change in the system time

Comment: +1, correct answer to one of the possible intents of an ambiguous question

Comment: Agreed, I'm sorry for the ambiguity.