# Is there a way to detect if the system clock has been changed backwards in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

On a windows machine, is there a way to find out if the time has been changed backwards without continually monitoring for WM_TIMECHANGE messages?

For example, I would like to make the first thing my application does on startup is see if the time has been changed back since I last run the application.

As far as I can tell, the only way to see a change is to look at the WM_TIMECHANGE message, but I will only see that if my application is running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an API event for when person changes clock on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756506/is-there-an-api-event-for-when-person-changes-clock-on-windows)

Comment: I 'd be very, very surprised if there were a way to do this. Also, it's not a dupe (the question explicitly states "without `WM_TIMECHANGE`").

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate as I'm looking to find if there is a way to detect a change after the fact. The other questions are about detecting a change when it happens.

Comment: Agreeing w/ Jon & Nick. This is a different situation. Not a dupe.

Comment: adding to the question: is there a way to see when the clock was changed even in the bios?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes. You can read the [Windows Event Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/event-logging) and look for changes to system time. (System time changes are one of the system events that are automatically logged.) For example, I just tweaked my system time by a few seconds and the following appeared in the System Event log:

> Information   10/21/2011 11:16:26 AM  Kernel-General  1   None
>
> The system time has changed to ‎2011‎-‎10‎-‎21T16:16:26.000000000Z
> from ‎2011‎-‎10‎-‎21T16:16:26.000000000Z.

You can [use the Win32 API to get access to the event logs](https://web.archive.org/web/20111102122233/http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnettips/article.php/c8897/) then query for these events to determine if the time was indeed altered. What's great about this solution is that it's built-in and always running. No need to monitor events via a custom service etc. You just query the OS's data.

**This is still not a bullet-proof solution** since people with admin rights can chance settings, clear logs etc. But you would definitely layperson-proof your app. System event logs are not something regular Windows users think about.

The XML for that particular event: (de-identified for privacy & security)

```
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General" 
        Guid="{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}" /> 
  <EventID>1</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000010</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-10-21T16:16:26.001000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>138478</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="40044" ThreadID="50016" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.org</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
  <Data Name="NewTime">2011-10-21T16:16:26.000000000Z</Data> 
  <Data Name="OldTime">2011-10-21T16:16:26.000000000Z</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. I've just checked my log and can see some time changes. I'm going to write a small utility to search for and dump out the changes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: But those events can be deleted, so it's still not a reliable source of information.

Comment: While an elegant solution, Paul, I would still maintain that this is not a canonical source and should not be relied on. There is NO way to actually determine if time has been changed. As a_horse mentioned, these events can be deleted, but they can also be entirely bypassed if you change the time from another OS on the same machine or from the BIOS itself.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I completely agree and a very similar caveat is mentioned in my answer. I'll bold it to make it stand out better.

Comment: @PaulSasik you don't even have to look for these specific events. There is a better way: the event record numbers are monotonically increasing. So if you cross-reference the event timestamps (seconds since Unix epoch, which is UTC) with the record numbers and discover considerable (define your own threshold) backdating you needn't even rely on these specific events still being there. But of course your method is equally valid, for the use cases where it matters I'd rather implement various methods anyway.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. That's why time-sensitive DRM schemes are in general rather useless.

You *could* try to work around it by using a service, and then you'd have to work around the service's downtime by using another hack, and another hack on top of that as well.

Anyway, if that's all you're trying to do then simply storing somewhere (encrypted, possibly) the value of the system time on your program's shutdown, then making sure that it has not been passed on program startup *should* be enough. It won't stop users that basically "froze" the time from shutdown to startup, but it'll be enough for 9/10 of the people trying to get past your timed trial.

Comment: Consider time zone changes or users crossing the date line.

Comment: @peterchen I don't know where this misconception comes from (I've seen it repeated in other articles on the topic), but in fact _most_ of the timestamps are stored as UTC (there _are_ exceptions!) and only when getting displayed will be shown for your current timezone. UTC has no DST adjustments either. So these are non-issues.

Comment: The answer itself makes assumptions. I would posit that it makes a big difference if you want to find out if the time was manipulated _across reboots_ or merely during the running session. The former is nigh impossible to prove without an external reference ("asking the internet") but the latter is much more manageable.

Comment: @0xC0000022L because that's how the world worked :)  Reliable time zone information only became available with ubiquitous internet, and I still have production data that is riddled with "well... that's probably local from... somewhere."
I concur that "remember to store UTC" would have been the better comment, in hindsight.

Comment: @peterchen my comment wasn't about "remember to store UTC", it's the mere statement that on Windows (NT) storing as UTC has been the default in most contexts for a very very long time. This is in no way something that was added only after 2011/2017. As such with those timestamps you needn't take care about time zone changes or date line. It's _just_ UTC for most timestamps (file system, object manager, registry). Again, there are _some_ exceptions, but if you pick the right ones you never had to worry about this in the first place. These timestamps are most relevant to detect tampering.

Answer (score 3):

You could have your app (while it happens to be running) periodically compare the system time with a time fetched from a server resource somewhere. If you suddenly see that the difference between system time and server time has increased, that means the system time has been set back.

Obviously this wouldn't work on a machine with no Internet access.

Comment: And an admin on a machine _with_ internet access has probably at least a dozen ways of letting your program "think" it's not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

One idea to that above (while I note that checking against an external clock is the definitive answer if feasible) - you can also periodically read the system clock and store it, perhaps encrypted, in a hidden file somewhere. Each time you do this you check to make sure the new value is more recent than the one in the file. The trigger to doing this could be at every startup etc.

Like all internal methods this one is vulnerable to someone figuring out the hidden file. You can also therefore flag a problem if the hidden file is missing, or if its date stamp doesn't match its contents.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.  You also don't need to include a disclosure unless your answer promotes a product, company, or web site that you're affiliated with.

Comment: What kind of encryption allows me _also_ to decrypt it again without at the same time giving the key into the hands of the (going by the subject matter) _untrusted_ user? Isn't that pretty much a catch 22?