# Who changes the time?

Tags: windows, winapi, time

I am aware of the WM_TIMECHANGE message in the Win32 API, but is it possible to find out which application or process is changing the time?

I have an application (Windows XP) where I'm logging events and the time logged with the events is changing unexpectedly.

I have already checked: Daylight Savings adjustment is turned off, and automatic syncing with an internet time server is also turned off.

Is there a process in the Windows OS (except for DST changes and NTP) that could set the system time?

Comment: Try [`SetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942(v=vs.85).aspx)function.

Comment: @S.MAHDI - sorry, perhaps I should rephrase the question - is there a process in the Windows OS (except DST changes) that could set the system time? (question edited)

Comment: Sorry, i have misunderstanding the question ..

Comment: @SteveFolly, malware probably. Check [Process Monitor] (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) , probably you can find the source. Another way is system-wide hook.

Comment: Did you see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852209/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-the-system-clock-has-been-changed-backwards-in-windo)?  Does that help?

Comment: A common scourge of XP with users logging in with an admin account.  Any process can change the time.  Lock down the box or upgrade the OS, UAC puts a stop to this.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, that has been useful.  But it looks like the problem was down to a dodgy RTC.  Windows was stripped to the minimum, and still the time was jumping.

Comment: @SteveFolly What do you mean by dodgy RTC? do you know how to disable the sync with RTC in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Time changes are saved to the [Windows Event Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically, they're saved to the security log.  Now, this isn't *guaranteed* to work; admins can clear the security log, but it's a way to find the PID and the file name of the process that called SetSystemTime.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852300/175201) talks about finding the event in the System log; however, you should also be able to find it in the Security log by looking for event ID 4616.  I've added a sample record here (with various bits redacted):

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" /> 
  <EventID>4616</EventID> 
  <Version>1</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>12288</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-10-07T18:55:08.999738200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>29419283</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="5460" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>some computer ID</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-SID_REDACTED</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">UserName</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">DOMAIN</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0xBADDFOOD</Data> 
  <Data Name="PreviousTime">2013-10-07T18:55:08.996254000Z</Data> 
  <Data Name="NewTime">2013-10-07T18:55:09.000000000Z</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessId">0xPID</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessName">C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe</Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Note that the process name is stored explicitly.