# How can I be informed when Windows update its system time?

Tags: windows, notifications

case: I dont allow my Windows PC to connect to internet. My PC uses internal clock. After a while, I connect my Windows PC into the network, and it receives time packages from internet and update its system time. Now, how can I get informed when my Windows Operating system received a time package and update its own system time from internet. I want to write an application which:
1- get informed about this receiveing time package (NTP) & time update, 
2- make own LOG (not very important how? just a printf is enough), like: "System Tiems is updated from 12.38 to 12:44".

Thank you guys for your info & help.
Regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the event log as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852209/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-the-system-clock-has-been-changed-backwards-in-windo)