# Get System Date Time Update log in Java

Tags: java, jar, system, executable-jar, clock

I would like to know is it possible to get system date time change log ( meaning thereby when User changed the time of SYSTEM) in Java.
What I am trying to implement : I have a JAR file in which I want to set some expire time. So, to detect any changes by User in the system, I want to compare the  time when the jar is having and comparing with System changes time log and decide to proceed or not.

Is there any such time log could be fetched from system through Java?

Comment: There might or might not be some native way to hook into a system time change event or process a time change log, but it depends entirely on the OS. An alternative could be to periodically poll the system time and check whether it is still in sync with your application's internal clock.

Comment: I think this is not possible in pure java but there definately are libraries for this, that implement this natively.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks for ur quick response. I don't have internal clock in JAR. I just donot want to use the JAR by user after a limited time.

Comment: @dan1st Thanks for your response. Do you know any such lib?

Comment: Maybe a more effective option is to use internet time from a remote server instead of leaning on the system time, which the user can manipulate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852209/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-the-system-clock-has-been-changed-backwards-in-windo

Comment: @ernest_k The JAR work on internal network. No internet connection.

Comment: So, if you just don't want the user to use the JAR after a certain time, why not just start a timer inside the JAR? If the timer expires, shut down the application.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen That's only going to work until the process is stopped... or the system restarted.

Comment: @ernest_k Yeah, I don't know what the requirements are here... Creating a JAR file that is no longer usable after some date? A JAR file that is no longer usable after *x* hours/days/... of usage?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes, you are right. A java JAR should not work after X hours/days/months/years.

Comment: So, *x* hours/days/... after it has been started? Or *x* hours/days/... after it has been created? Or...?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen after its creation more precisely.

Comment: Like mentioned in the answer linked by @Shailesh, there's no bullet-proof solution. As long as you don't have access to an authoritative time source, anything goes...

Comment: I would suggest you access open NTP in your code and compare your date/time in code , that's how I will do it because keeping track in local will not be fruitful in case your user take a snapshot of library  and keep replacing latest version with snapshot  which might have older date. 

Also keep comparison properties encrypted etc etc

Comment: @Shailesh But, limitation is here that, JAR could be running on machine having no internet connectivity, possible single machine also. I guess NTP also requires internet.

Comment: Such implementation are always prone to break, a fully motivated developer can crack it sooner or later, you need to keep a local track for time, also  rely on encryption but nothing will stop a developer to keep a copy of executable directory  and reuse it later if you are keeping track in file system, on windows you can rely on windows registry (given you have access) . you can enforce internet connection every n days etc but in more case it's a lost battle.

Comment: This has been asked a number of times before. Please search. You can get some of the way with `System.nanoTime()`, but it doesn’t work across system reboots.