# Detect date/time format change in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-runtime

I have an application that's long running (and nearly always displayed) that shows the current time.  Currently, if you change the timezone, time format, or language the format doesn't change unless I quit and restart the application.  How can I detect when these change so that I can immediately refresh the formatting?

Note that this is native, not managed code (and I can't change that), so anything that's managed-only is right out.

Comment: See [Is there an API event for when person changes clock on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/756506/719186)

Comment: Not managed.  Will edit to be clear.  (Although the WinAPI tag should imply that ;)).  Although WM_TIMECHANGED might be what I need.

Comment: `WM_TIMECHANGE` for sure.  Maybe also look at [`ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms628769.aspx) and [`WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632629.aspx), and maybe [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the timezone sends a [WM_TIMECHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725498.aspx) message to all top-level windows, while changing the time format sends a [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx) message. Changing the language (system locale) requires a reboot and so doesn't send a message.